# Two model type in one View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a concern.
I am populating a list from controller and showing a table. Now upon clicking of a button in table row, i want to populate modal popup for webform, which is a partial view.
My problem is, when i am using List Type model, i am not able to convert that model from list to simple as i have to pass simple model to render webform. My code is as below:

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model List<MvcApplication3.Models.ModelList>
//////
////
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    // foreach is used to show data in table
    @Html.Parial("PartialView")
}
```

**ModelList.cs**

```
public class ModelList
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
    public string Product { set; get; }
    public string Status { set; get; }
    public string Password { set; get; }
    public string Email { set; get; }
}
```

**PartialView.cshtml**

```
@model MvcApplication3.Models.ModelList
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
////
}
```

**Controller**

```
List<ModelList> objList = new List<ModelList>();
return View(objList);
```

How can i be able to use same model in both ways.

Comment: why are you doing foreach?

Comment: `@Html.Partial("PartialView", item)` will generate a partial for each item in the collection

Comment: to show data in table

Comment: @Mayank Using loops in a view is bad practice. Try looking into EditorTemplates and DisplayTemplates instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    // foreach is used to show data in table
    @Html.Partial("PartialView", item)
}
```

You need to tell it to use your item in the partial

Comment: Thanks John... now i am able to show webform... but now when i am submitting from partial view it is not redirecting to controller\

Comment: @Mayank, Different issue, so ask a new question with the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

try to use IEnumeraible in your index.cshtml view and then loop it and pass every new instance of ModelList to PartialView like this:

**index.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumeraible<MvcApplication3.Models.ModelList>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.Parial("PartialView", item)
}
```